# weird stationary pattern in LDO.MI's stock price

Tags: market-microstructure, spread, liquidity

how to describe this pattern in Leonardo Finmeccanica's share price (observed [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LDO.MI?ltr=1))? It is a fairly liquid stock, but the price seems to alternate between ca. 8 and ca 13!!

Does anyone know what could explain this observation?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the least interesting pattern of all - data errors at the Yahoo's side. Just checked with Bloomberg - nothing similar is present.

If not a data error, this could be bid-ask bounce (dismissed with here since you mention it's a liquid stock).